# How Can I Help My Community?

Tags: raspbian

For my junior year in high school I want to host a Raspberry Pi Jam to "decorate" my college application and help out my community. The jam would probably be aimed towards younger teens  and their parents, if they wanted to see what is going on. How could I get this started? Since would a junior in high school (17 years old) I am not going to have enough money to do this all by myself. Is there a way I could apply for a sponsorship and raise funds? Since I want to help the community I want to make this event available for free so more disadvantaged people could join. So to recap, how could I get this event started and how could I apply for a sponsorship? Also, if you can link to any helpful projects to do with raspberry pi beginners that would be great!

Comment: Have you considered asking the raspberrypi foundation? Or some other Pi jam organizers?

Comment: When do you want to do this? I can sponsor a kit or two from fa4nell/amadong for your JAM but I need to know its going to happen and a few more details, etc.

Comment: It will be around next year, I still want to talk with friends about it before we plan it. Thank you for that, I will get back to you though in about a year, when we are ready to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is new section on the Foundations site http://www.raspberrypi.org/jam/ which also has a page on how to host your Jam http://www.raspberrypi.org/jam/how/ including getting sponsership.

Personally I would look for local businesses to sponsor, its good publicity especially if you can local press involved.

Comment: Those links do provide allot of information about what the OP is talking about. It seems like allot of work todo before even having the Pi's.